# How to let special XML chars unconverted in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

That's my xml node:

```
 <node att="something &lt; something else"> </node>
```

When i write in my code :

```
trace(xml.node.@att.toString());
```

it prints out the string :

> something < something else

My problem is that i need to print out the orriginal string:

```
 something $lt; something else //put $ instead of &
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey !
Just tried this and it seems to work... : )

```
var xml:XML=<node att="something &lt; something else"> </node>;
trace(xml.toXMLString());//<node att="something &lt; something else"/>
trace(xml.@att.toXMLString());//something &lt; something else
```

Comment: Oh, yes, toXMLString should produce valid xml, so it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic XML Parser will unespace them.

If you want the converted char again, you'll need to reconvert it again using ActionScript 3.

You can also convert it twice, using `&amp;lt;`

Comment: my problem is at "return" char. I have it represented as "&#xA;", and its equivalent from AS is "\n". But when i reconvert it doesn't work. Seem like "&#xA;" is not equivalent to "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - USE `<![CDATA[ ]]>`

```
<chapter title="hello" nr="111" src="">
  <page>
    <text><![CDATA[To adjust <br/><br/>. . .  ]]></text>
    <text><![CDATA[To adjust <br/><br/>. . .  ]]></text>
  </page>
</chapter>
```

Option 2 - use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for < and >

Then `<br/>` = `&lt;b/&gt;`